# Deserialize jSON Google Ajax Web API

Tags: c#, json

I've got this JSON coming back like this:

```
{"responseData": {"results":[{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.hellomagazine.com/","url":"http://www.hellomagazine.com/","visibleUrl":"www.hellomagazine.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:QzMhUCC4zBoJ:www.hellomagazine.com","title":"\u003cb\u003eHELLO\u003c/b\u003e! - The place for celebrity news - hellomagazine.com","titleNoFormatting":"HELLO! - The place for celebrity news - hellomagazine.com","content":"News and pictures from the world of celebrity, royalty, entertainment, film and   music; fashion trends and videos; health and beauty; celebrity profiles; \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v\u003dPDZcqBgCS74","url":"http://www.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DPDZcqBgCS74","visibleUrl":"www.youtube.com","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:0rcBZ0fdKWMJ:www.youtube.com","title":"YouTube - Lionel Richie - \u003cb\u003eHello\u003c/b\u003e","titleNoFormatting":"YouTube - Lionel Richie - Hello","content":"\u003cb\u003eHello\u003c/b\u003e, you either have JavaScript turned off or an old version of Adobe\u0026#39;s Flash   Player \u003cb\u003e....\u003c/b\u003e \u003cb\u003eHello\u003c/b\u003e; Is it you you\u0026#39;re calling me? I can hear it in your voice. \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://www.elite.net/~runner/jennifers/hello.htm","url":"http://www.elite.net/~runner/jennifers/hello.htm","visibleUrl":"www.elite.net","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:SeJdgQcmMU8J:www.elite.net","title":"\u0026quot;\u003cb\u003eHello\u003c/b\u003e\u0026quot; in many languages","titleNoFormatting":"\u0026quot;Hello\u0026quot; in many languages","content":"Feb 28, 2008 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e At this site you can learn how to say \u003cb\u003ehello\u003c/b\u003e in more than 775 languages from   around the world. My goal is to include every language, \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"},{"GsearchResultClass":"GwebSearch","unescapedUrl":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello","url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello","visibleUrl":"en.wikipedia.org","cacheUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?q\u003dcache:oCsA1meBGrMJ:en.wikipedia.org","title":"\u003cb\u003eHello\u003c/b\u003e - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","titleNoFormatting":"Hello - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia","content":"Many stories date the first use of \u003cb\u003ehello\u003c/b\u003e (with that spelling) to around the time   of the invention of the telephone in 1876. It was, however, used in print \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e"}],"cursor":{"pages":[{"start":"0","label":1},{"start":"4","label":2},{"start":"8","label":3},{"start":"12","label":4},{"start":"16","label":5},{"start":"20","label":6},{"start":"24","label":7},{"start":"28","label":8}],"estimatedResultCount":"85000000","currentPageIndex":0,"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den\u0026q\u003dhello"}}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

How can I parse it and get a List with title and url? Thanks
C#

Answer (score 1):

MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This [site](http://www.davidcodeproject.com/youtube) demos searching and parsing the JSON of search results.  View Source on your browser and look at the showMyVideos() in the html.